# Как написать текст в Panel

Tags: c#

Как написать текст внутри Panel в C#?

Comment: по-моему Panel это контейнер (может дотнетчики меня поправят)

Конечно скорее всего можно извратится и например переопределить метод OnDraw (или что-то подобное). Но лучше использовать контролы предназначенные для вывода текста

Comment: Пусть автор сначала хоть чтото по шарпу прочитает

Comment: просто в Delphi было такое и для этого достаточно было набрать:
panel1.Caption и писать текст. Но тут нет такого, а я новичок в C#, поэтому и решил спросить

Comment: @rasmisha прав, `Panel` - это контейнер, и текст на нём написать нельзя, так что используйте элемент `Label`

Comment: может вам нужен не `Panel` а `GroupBox`?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужна панель с заголовком, используйте компонент `GroupBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы правильно написать текст внутри панели, достаточно в дизайнере щелкнуть двойным щелчком мыши и в новом событии воспользоваться методом e.Graphics.DrawString("",.....); . Есть также GroupBox.

Comment: не костыль?

Comment: @rasmisha вообще вопрос нарывается на минус, так как написать текст можно по-разному

Comment: первый коммент к вопросу как раз об этом

Comment: @Spectre поэтому и ответом не стал публиковать, потому что костыль